# Possible method using Switch Statement against a list using Contains

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

For efficiency is there a possible method similar to a switch statement which can be used against lists?

e.g:

```
    switch (List)
    {
        case contains("admin"):
        permission = x;
        break;
        case contains("user"):    
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Admin);
        break;
        case contains("user2"):    
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Admin);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Dates);
        break;
        case contains("guest"): 
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Admin);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Dates);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Data);
        break;
    }
```

instead of having an if contains for each contains

Comment: So, if a list contains "admin" and "user" and "guest", you want all three code pieces to be executed, right? If yes, then `if` is the best option to do this. If you want only the first matching part to be executed (`switch`-alike), then use LINQ `FirstOrDefault` on the array of possible values.

Comment: I don't think so, if it contains "admin" it will not be tested for "user"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
if (List.Contains(value))
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case "admin": permission = x;
            break;
        case "user": tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Admin);
            break;
        case "user2": tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Admin);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Dates);
            break;
        case "guest": tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Admin);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Dates);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tab_Data);
            break;
    }
}
```

The issue is the [List.Contains method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a *boolean* value so you cannot use it like that.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding this won't work as where you say "Value" I'll need to specify a string, which would make the switch within pointless as the value would be set to a single string. This works great as a for each however